# Trying regex, simple example won't work

Tags: c, regex

This is my first time working with regular expressions. What I need is something that matches `u<float>v<float>`, but for now I'll settle for something that matches `u<float>` with the float being in the open unit interval. [This](https://regexr.com/) neat site got me to the following expression:

`u0.\d+` "match u, zero, a dot, and one or more digits"

Then I wanted to try it in C, as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    regex_t regex;
    char *regex_str = "u0.\\d+";
    regcomp(&regex, regex_str, 0);

    char *str = "u0.51";

    int status = regexec(&regex, str, (size_t)0, NULL, 0);
    printf("Status: %d\n", status);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, according to `man regexec`, `regexec` returns zero on match. The above returns 1. What's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to check if regcomp compiles.
And to regfree(&regex) when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need escape the `.` as it is a regular expression meta character that matches *any* one character. To escape it, prefix it with `\`. However `\` is a meta char in C string literals well, so you must escape *that*, therefore getting `\\.`.

`\d` is a Perl-compatible regular expression idiom that matches a single digit. It is not present in POSIX regular expressions - thus you must use `[0-9]` instead. Lastly, `+` is not a metacharacter in *basic* regular expressions - you must use `REG_EXTENDED`. Therefore we have

```
const char *regex_str = "u0\\.[0-9]+";
regcomp(&regex, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED);
```

Comment: Finally it works, thank you! I'll work from there and try to get what I really want, thanks again!

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Notice that `sscanf` *might* just work for this too, if all you need is to actually parse the floating point numbers

Comment: Haha that's actually what I've tried so far, with `atof`, but no luck so I turned to regex. Good excuse to learn that important part of CS, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which function to use, but according to my experience, you need to use **Extended** regular expression to make the plus sign work.

Also the `\d` notation is not a part of POSIX RegEx. It's possibly part of PCRE (Perl-Compatible RegEx), so it may not work with what `regex.h` supplies.

Try this code:

```
chat *regex_str = "u0\\.[0-9]+"
regcomp(&regex, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED);
```